# Fix needed for editing/triage overlap

Tags: discussion, triage

I popped up a second copy of the question in the Triage review queue, and noticed that:

- The question was only 45 secs old
- The edit notifications do not appear in the triage window

Real-world triage typically occurs *after* the scene is secured.

The danger is that a new user may occasionally be cleaning up their question in the 2-3 minutes it takes for another group to shoot it down as unsalvageable.  That's not a positive experience, and I think we want to keep new users who can see the edit link and the need to use it.

I suggest, then:

- Don't triage until the question has been up for at least 2-3 minutes. Despite proofreading being a best practice, often people don't really proofread until the question is up on the site because only then does the stress of public exposure set in.
- If an *edited* warning indicator is not feasible or inexpensive, then further delay triage after every edit, as some people are serial editors.

The goal should be to Triage once a question seems stable.

If this needs to be balanced vs. junk, then posts by people who have previously posted junk but never edited could be triaged immediately. That should allow quickly eliminating the junk.  Whether that also applies to first timers is probably 'yes' on the probabilities but unclear when it comes to encouraging useful participation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Right now, we're following the same model here as we do with suggested edits: tasks are created *immediately* and concurrent reviews are blocked, meaning the first reviewer can see the post within seconds of its creation (as you observed) but further reviews must wait until the first reviewer is done.

We might change that a bit if we need reviews to happen even faster, but right now >50% of tasks are *completed* within 8 minutes... So that's not too shabby:

[image: Triage review task completion time]
*% of review tasks completed by minute*

If the speed becomes a problem in practice, we can consider other options here - including just notifying reviewers when an edit has been performed. However, I don't expect that this will make much difference: even if an edit is performed after the first reviewer loads the question, subsequent reviewers will still see the updated question. Since a 3-review majority is required to complete the task, substantive changes to the question soon after it is posted should still result in an accurate review.